# HTML select TAG into mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, tags, html-select

So, I want to upload a file and choose (for example) "Value 1" from select tag. And then when I click Publish button I want from script to check if I selected Value 1, and if I did, then I want to put the file ("file_name") it in column "columndb", if I selected Value 2 I want to put it in some other column and so on.

```
<div><input type="file" name="file_name">    
<div><input type="file" name="inputname">
       <select id="select_id" name="select_name">
       <option value="null">None</option>
       <option value="value1" name="value1name">Value 1</option>
       <option value="value2" name="value2name">Value 2</option>
       </select></div>
<div>
<div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Publish"></div>
</div>    
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$filename = $_FILES['file_name']['name'];
$filename_tmp = $_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name'];
$select_tag = $_POST['select_name'];

move_uploaded_file($filename_tmp, "somewhere/$filename");

if($select_tag == 'value1name'){

        $insert_db = "insert into mydb ('columndb') values ('$filename')";
        $run_db = mysqli_query($db, $insert_db, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `if($select_tag == 'value1name')` will never evaluate to that. You're checking against a name attribute instead of a value. Plus, `<option>` does not hold the name attribute, only `<select>` does.

Comment: you're also using the wrong identifier qualifiers in your query.

Comment: I tried with 'if($select_tag == 'value1')' and it doesn't work.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($db))` to `mysqli_query()`. You now have enough to debug your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options shouldn't have names, only values.
So you would verify as follows:

```
if($select_tag == "value1")
{
   //...
   //You're also using apostrophes in the query, on the column name, which is wrong.
   //Change to this:
   $insert_db = "insert into mydb (`columndb`) values ('$filename')";
}
```

Comment: Problem was exactly like you said, values in options and apostrophes in the query. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If $select_tag is correctly holding the 'value' of your selection as the column name, then the following should be suitable:

```
$insert_db = "insert into mydb (`$select_tag`) values ('$filename')";
```

As a note though, using the value from the form as the column name is very bad security-wise. Someone malicious could manually submit a value which causes data to be put into another field, or perform an sql injection (because you do not escape the $select_tag or $filename before performing your SQL query.

You'd be better off having a block of 'if' statements, or a 'switch', which chooses a column depending on a predefined set of values.

Example:

```
$target_column = ""; // input column
switch($select_tag) {
    case "column1":
        $target_column = "columndb";
        break;

    case "column2":
        $target_column = "anothercolumn";
        break;

    default:
        $target_column = "column1";
        break;
}

$filename = mysql_escape_string($filename); // mysql_escape_string is deprecated in later php versions... Use an alternative like mysqli_real_escape_string()
$insert_db = "insert into mydb (`$target_column`) values ('$filename')";
$run_db = mysqli_query($db, $insert_db, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
```

Comment: Thank you for security info.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($_POST['select_tag'] == 'Something') {
```

I think this is what you want